# Exclude folders from search result

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I am using sitecore 7 Lucene search.  When I search for any term, the search results show all folders and pages.  Can I exclude folders from the search result? I have following code to search documents from index.

```csharp
var searcher = Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");
            using (var context = searcher.CreateSearchContext())
            {
                var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>();

                var result = query.Where(x => (x.Content.Contains(_searchTerm));

                globalResults = result.GetResults();

            }
```

Comment: please edit your question to add more detail. For example, the code for your search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `SearchResultItem` has a `TemplateId` property, so you can filter out folder items using that.

```csharp
var result = query.Where(x => (x.Content.Contains(_searchTerm) &&
                               x.TemplateId.ToString() != "{--Folder-template-id--}");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to limit your search to a specific folder you can add something like this:

```
var TopSearchFolderID = new Guid("{A5D56753-E5E4-42A1-AD3E-4B43C70CC618}");
var result = query.Where(x => x.Content.Contains(_searchTerm) & x._path == TopSearchFolderID.ToString("N"));
```

If you wish to exclude specific folders you can do something like this:

```
var FolderToExcludeID = new Guid("{A5D56753-E5E4-42A1-AD3E-4B43C70CC618}");
var result = query.Where(x => x.Content.Contains(_searchTerm) & x._path != FolderToExcludeID.ToString("N"));
```