# Sitecore 7, Content Search, "Content" property of the document is not showing actual content

Tags: search, sitecore, sitecore7

I have managed to get search results using LINQ way, I can access different fields of the searched document, including `Title`, `Url`, `Path`, etc.

I can also access `Content` property of the document but that is not showing actual content of the document. It is showing `Title` of the document separated by `-`, for example if the searched document `Title` is `Video news items`, `Content` property contains `Video-news-items|Video news items`.

How can I get actual content of the searched document?

Code I am using to search document is explained in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602779/sitecore-7-exclude-folders-from-search-result).

Comment: Why do you need to access the content through the index at all? Usually the content isn't stored in the index 1:1. Instead just use LINQ to query the object and then use the returned item IDs in your result set to get your item through the Sitecore API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602779/sitecore-7-exclude-folders-from-search-result), I assume you are using the base `SearchResultItem` class. You can inherit from this class and add Properties that map to specific fields in your items. you can then just use the properties as normal. This article explains the process:

[Sitecore 7 POCO's explained](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/06/Sitecore-7-POCO-Explained.aspx)

If you haven't yet done any research into Sitecore 7 search yet, I would suggest that you do some. The concepts may not be familiar.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is showing meta title for this page